# What causes this \endcsname error?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, errors

I am a beginner to LaTeX, and I don't understand what's going wrong here. I didn't change anything, and all of a sudden, the code won't run. Can you please help me?

```
) (./Final_Halper_410Latex.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.22 \@writefile
                {toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {II}Methods}{2}{}}
?
```

The relevant lines of code are as follows:

```
\pdfoutput=1 % For pdflatex
\documentclass[aps,prd,floatfix,nofootinbib,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

%Uncomment the two lines below if you are using BibTex
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright} %Removes strange justification problems in bibliography when using Bibtex and Revtex 4-1

\begin{document}
.
.
.
\section{Methods}
```

Comment: There are some possible reasons. Most likely here is a 'fragile' command written to the Table of contents. You should give us more information, i.e. the minimal document that produces this error

Comment: This error can arise in a few different ways. Would you be able to edit your question to include the code that reproduces this error?

Comment: Can you give me a for instance?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Like this? \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {II}Methods}{2}{}}

Comment: @Nicole: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The document is really long and has images in it. I don't understand what an MWE is. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Nicole: Follow the link in my comment. Apparently, the error occurs in the second section, rather early in the document

Comment: @Nicole: Sorry, that code isn't compilable due to a missing `\end{document}` and after adding it, there's no error!

Comment: Ok... there's an \end{document} in my code.

Comment: @Nicole: No, there's no `\end{document}` in your post above. Whatever you have done, the fragment above does not produce the error you've reported.

Comment: the error is on line 21 (unshown) of your aux file which will be most likely some kind of heading or label command, most likely it is messes up as there is an error in your source in the corresponding heading. You need to fix your source _and_ delete the aux file so a good aux file can be generated. But unless you show some relevant code in the example, we can not offer much help with the fix.